# confidence interval of the standard deviation with proc sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

My data set is really simple, just one colum with a ratio and another colum with a categorical var, I need to calculate  the standard deviation for each class as well as the confidence interval.

Is there a built in function in SAS (proc SQL) to calculate the conficende interval of the standar deviation???
something like the excel function confidence() does?

thanks!

Comment: Why are you asking for PROC SQL specifically?  There are lots of built in procedures in SAS happy to provide you both of those values more efficiently than coding it in PROC SQL.

Comment: for example? i just had it all done with proc SQL and wondered if it was possible with a function.. but im open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Proc SQl but PROC Univariate will give you the confidence intervals of mean, standard deviations and variance. The details are available in SAS support documents:

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_sect064.htm

The following statements produce confidence limits for the mean, standard deviation, and variance of the population of heights:

```
ods select BasicIntervals;
proc univariate data=Heights cibasic;
   var Height;
run;
```